# TraceID for a request is not travelling between services( Using the Same Trace ID in Zipkin with Spring Boot 3.1.2 and Spring Cloud 2022.0.4 )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, zipkin

I'm working with Spring Boot 3.1.2 and Spring Cloud 2022.0.4, and I'm measuring metrics with an Eureka Server and Zipkin. However, I've noticed that requests I make to the customer service in Zipkin are generating different trace IDs compared to other requests. What kind of configuration should I use to ensure that requests are traced with the same trace ID?

My current configuration for my base module is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kemalyuksel</groupId>
    <artifactId>kemalyukselservices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>kemalyukselservices</name>

    <modules>
        <module>customer</module>
        <module>fraud</module>
        <module>eureka-server</module>
        <module>clients</module>
        <module>notification</module>
    </modules>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>3.1.2</spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>
        <spring.boot.dependencies.version>3.1.2</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kemalyuksel
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    networks:
      - zipkin

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge
  zipkin:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

**and my child module pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.kemalyuksel</groupId>
        <artifactId>kemalyukselservices</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>customer</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-sender-urlconnection</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-sender-okhttp3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kemalyuksel</groupId>
            <artifactId>clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  application:
    name: notification
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/notification
    username: kemalyuksel
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true


eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
    propagation:
      type: b3

#logging.pattern.level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

**customer service :**

[image: customerservice]

**zipkin result :**

[image: zipkinresult]

Do you have any suggestions or corrections regarding the Spring Boot, Spring Cloud, Zipkin, and Eureka configurations? I want to trace my requests with the same trace ID.

Thank you.

I have tried different packages and different configuration settings, but I couldn't succeed.